# Confusing get resourcename when read resource in winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, resources, .net-assembly, streamreader

I have added a text file resource into my winform C# project in Resource Folder
Here the content of Resources.resx after I add

```
<data name="_0" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
<value>..\Resources\0.txt;System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;Windows-1252</value>
```

and then I try to read the content of that embedded resourde using this solution before

[How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

Here is the main program

```
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = "Properties.Resources.0.txt"; 
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

but I got null parameter in var reader, I think it's about the path of resource name, any IDEA to solve my problem?
thanks before

Comment: Paste the code you are using to read the embedded file please

Comment: Oh I finally solved, the problem is my file embedded has no include in resource list, to insert in resource list you can right click in the file (in Solution Explorer Visual Studio), and then change the build action properties into Embedded Resource To view resourcename you can use method String[] list = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

Answer (score 0):

You have to append YOUR project namespace to the resourcename:

```
var resourceName = "Properties.Resources.0.txt";
```

Change it to:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "ProjectNamespace.Properties.Resources.0.txt";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: then does the namespace is same with project name I created?
For example if I create project ReadResource, then it will same as ProjectNamespace name?
If so, I have changed but not change the result

Comment: The namespace is defined by you. But if you did not changed it, it is the project name. For example if I create a project named: SportSTore and add a Resource called myFile.txt. The full resource path is SportStore.Properties.myFile.txt